# Can simple .Net core model binder bind json query string param?

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-5, model-binding

I have the following:

```
    public class TestClass
    {
        public string? MyString { get; set; }
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("test")]
    public void Test([FromQuery] TestClass myTest)
```

The following will **successfully** bind:

https://localhost:5001/test?MyString=test

The following will **not**:

https://localhost:5001/test?myTest={%22MyString%22:%22test%22}

### Question

Is it possible to configure the out-of-the-box model binder in a way in which it will parse 1 query string parameter as json? (i.e. the second approach)

### What I've Tried

I've tried naming the parameter as part of the `[FromQuery]`, that doesn't work (i.e. doesn't bind).

I've also tried removing `[FromQuery]`, that doesn't bind either.

### Further Context

For one reason or another I cannot change how the client sends this data, I can only change the server.

Comment: what about `https://localhost:5001/test?MyString={%22MyString%22:%22test%22}`?

Comment: @LeiYang - that doesn't work, as you would expect that just binds the whole json blob to the `MyString` property, that's not what I'm after. I want it to deserialize/parse the json.

Comment: why not deserialize/parse in (your) code? if you want the framework do for you, you may prefer http body, instead of query parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but not that way.

What your code is doing is telling the framework to look for a parameter named 'MyString' in the query string.

Instead, you should be looking into the `Request` object that is accessible in your controller. This contains the entire HTTP request from the user so you can look at headers, query string, form data, etc.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.request?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2